# Pull Couchbase database over ssh from remote server

Tags: ssh, debian, database

I am working on a Debian environment and I have to pull a Couchbase database from a remote server location into my local Dev environment.

I wasn't able to find any kind of details on this topic so any kind of assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by pull?  Is it pull the database over? cbbackup/cbrestore is one option, and cbtransfer and the built in XDCR.  The former is better for one-time setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual trick is using `scp`. The usual is:

```
scp user@remotemachine:/path/to/remote/file.db /path/to/local/dir/
```

You may be able to use a password, or SSH (scp runs under ssh) may be configured to require a Keyfile to log in. Try the copy, see if your password can work.

There is a simple [tutorial here](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).

Answer (score 1):

There are two tools depending on the version of Couchbase you use:

**cbbackupmgr:**

- Full backup

  Create repo:

  > cbbackupmgr config -a "backups_directory" -r "backup_name"

  Create backup:

  > cbbackupmgr backup -a "backups_directory" -r "backup_name" -c
  >   couchbase://"ip_date_node" -u "user" -p "password"
- Restore (the bucket must be empty):

  > cbbackupmgr restore -a "backups_directory" -r "backup_name" -c
  >   couchbase://"ip_date_node" -u "user" -p "pass"

**cbbackup and cbrestore:**

- Backup:

  > cbbackup couchbase://"ip_date_node":8091 "backup_name" -u "user" -p
  >   "pass"
- Restore (the bucket must be empty):

  > cbrestore ~/backup couchbase://ip_date_node:8091 -b "backup_name"

More info: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/backup-restore/backup-restore.html